# Issue finding account details

Tags: support, android-app, stack-exchange, user-accounts, account-recovery

I've asked before and couldn't get a definitive answer,  and I tried poking around myself for very long with no success so I will try again to explain my issue as clearly as possible.  I am running the stack exchange app on my android smart phone.  I've had it for a long time and it just auto logs in on its own.

I want to be able to log in now on my pc and other devices and I have forgotten any account details like password,  or even the email I used to create the account.  All I have is my user name,  as we can all see it.

Given my situation in what way can I go about finding out my the email used or doing a reset password, or is there any advice anyone could give me on how to deal with this problem.  Thx

Comment: I will try to search all my email accounts for a confirmation email from stack exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK,  so I've done a search through all of my email accounts for an account confirmation email from Stack Exchange, and I was able to find the email that I had used.

I then went to the desktop site and did an account recovery which let me reset my password. I hope this can help anyone who has experienced the same problem.